# How do I select a radio button onload AND parse the value

Tags: html, radio-button, onload

I've successfully figured out how to have a radio button selected upon load, but I've yet to figure out how to make the value for that button appear without having to click on the radio button. I'm attempting to show/hide various divs, but I'd like for the first div to show as the page loads rather than nothing at all. Thanks for any help.

```
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        document.myForm.options[0].checked = true;
      }
    </script> 


<style>
    .box{
        padding: 0px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }


[type='radio'] {
margin-left:50px;
margin-right:5px;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="first"){
            $(".box").not(".first").hide();
            $(".first").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="second"){
            $(".box").not(".second").hide();
            $(".second").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="third"){
            $(".box").not(".third").hide();
            $(".third").show();
        }

    });
});
</script>



<form name="myForm">
<input type="radio" value="first" id="maina" name="options">SHOW FIRST
<input type="radio" value="second" id="maina" name="options">SHOW SECOND
<input type="radio" value="third" id="maina" name="options">SHOW THIRD
</form>




<div class="first box">
first div
</div>



<div class="second box">
second div
</div>



<div class="third box">
third div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just explicitly tell the first box to show, regardless of the other box settings?

```
.first {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but I added that line to my css and it didn't work. Removing anything else ruined the entire code. I get the logic behind what you're saying, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Thanks for the prompt reply, btw.

Comment: Oh, maybe it's my browser. I'm using Chrome. When I clicked your link, I saw the 3 choice --- none of them were checked --- and no divs were showing. I also found no mention of your "display:block" suggestion. What I was hoping to accomplish would've been if your fiddle displayed all 3 choices with the first already marked and the first div already shown without me having to click anything. I hope I'm explaining myself well enough. I've done a lot of digging on this, so maybe also let me know if this is impossible. I really do appreciate your help a great deal.

Comment: I think I screwed up and forgot to update my fiddle before I linked it to you.  Sorry about that.  Regardless, here's an alternative, then:  put the command to show the first div at the end of the `$(document).ready` function.  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vjhgo975/2/)

And here's my original attempt, using the CSS `display:block`: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vjhgo975/3/)

Comment: Figured it out. style="display:block;" must be placed within the first div. <div class="first box" style="display:block;"> ---  THANKS A TON!